# React Native - How to make a variable global from my fetch method

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, fetch-api

I have a method where I fetch an API, get the highest value from it's tables ID and then give that value to a global variable.

However `componentDidMount` does the fetching later, so my app says 'undefined' instead of fetching first and then assigning the value to the variable.

Code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        id: '',
    };
}



fetchData = () => {
            fetch(url)
                .then(request => request.json())
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        data: response,
                        id:Math.max.apply(Math, response.map(function (o) { return o.id; })) + 1,
                    });
console.log(this.state.id) // this gives me the highest id + 1 /here it works but check the render method!
                });
        }


componentDidMount = () => {
            this.fetchData();
        }


render() {
    return (
        <View
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <ScrollView>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={this.state.id} //here it uses the original states value which is empty ('') and not the one from the fetch' setState...why?
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'id')}
                />

            </ScrollView>

        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If render is not getting the updated value, it would seem like the fetch call is not working??

Comment: Can you console.log(this.state) before the return ?

Comment: Don't put this in global, you can make it work on state easily. We just need more info, about what is the response and what is the state after the render. Also here you get undefined, cause global.id dont exist until you fill it.

Comment: @EQuimper I get data from the api, use a function to get the highes ID, add a 1 to it and that value should be an placeholder in the renders text method.

Comment: @EQuimper I also went the state route (check the updated code), but that also gives me undefined in the code.

Comment: This is in android ?

Comment: react native, create-react-native-app..javascript

Comment: @epascarello fetch works, tested it but it only console.logs its value when I'm in the fetch method and outside of it says undefined and I don't quite understand that.

Comment: I know this is react-native, what I mean is android textinput placeholder if I remember dont rerender, can you try it with value and see if that work ?

Comment: My guess is your code is working fine, it is with one of your components not rendering with the updated data.

Comment: @EQuimper GOD BLESS YOU. I changed it to > placeholder={`${this.state.id}`} and now it works. Thanks! Answer and I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @epascarello Correct, the code was fine, I had to change the placeholder value format into placeholder={`${this.state.id}`}. Thanks!

Comment: but be careful, the `state` scope is not the `global` scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to `global` scope. 
ex: `global.myVar = "my global variable"`

Comment: Now when I do a console.log(global.id). It says undefined. It also prints that before the fetch so maybe it has something to do with react native doing the fetch method afterwards? So your response worked but I see the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: yes, print the `console.log` when the `fetch` is done, when the promise is resolved.

Comment: Sure, that gives me the wanted number, but I need that value in the textinput as placeholder, and there it stays undefined even when I use the global variable from the fetch method where it gives the correct number.

Comment: that is a different issue :) Until then pls mark the answer as ok for the initial question. Regarding your new issue, I guess you should set your placeholder in the `state` and change the `state` with the `global.yourVar`